# Book or other resources on activities for teaching Chinese grammar?

Tags: teaching-methods, grammar, chinese

I am looking for a book or other resources about tasks and activities for *teaching* Chinese grammar. There are book on teaching English grammar, e.g. [Task-based grammar teaching of English](http://www.narr-studienbuecher.de/index.php/14-roksprocket-mosaic/163-task-based-grammar-teaching-of-english) by Susanne Niemeier (Narr, 2017), but it is difficult to find resources on teaching Chinese grammar.

What I mean by tasks and activities are things like the board race in the YouTube video [teaching english grammar through games](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GieAxHSkxvM). However, not every activity needs to be physical. The main criterion for the resource I am interested it is that it goes beyond explaining grammar and then handing out exercises on paper (fill in the blanks, reformulate sentences, ...).

The resource I am looking for should provide examples of activities, not just theory about teaching. A book (in English, German, French or Dutch) is fine; a YouTube channel dedicated to this topic would also work. (Grammar books from which you *learn* grammar don't count.)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of books that may be helpful:

- Jianhua Bai (Kenyon College, Middlebury College): *[Chinese Grammar Made Easy: A Practical and Effective Guide for Teachers](https://yalebooks.yale.edu/book/9780300122794/chinese-grammar-made-easy)*, Yale University Press, 2008 (336 pages). According to the publisher's website, this book "presents instructors with innovative and classroom-tested techniques for teaching Chinese grammar". It is designed as a reference for teaching the "150 of the most fundamental and frequently used grammar points that students need to learn in order to communicate successfully". These grammar points include "A 比 B", "是 ... 的"， "为了", "一 ... 就 ...", etcetera. The book came out of a three-year research project and pays attention to the sequencing of grammar points and scaffolding in Chinese language instruction.
- Janet Zhiqun Xing: [*Teaching and Learning Chinese as a Foreign Language: A Pedagogical Grammar*](http://ebooks.hkupress.org/product/teaching-learning-chinese-as-foreign-language). Hong Kong University Press, 1993. ISBN 978-962-209-763-6. This is another book that claims to provide "a research-based account of how to teach and learn Chinese as a foreign language".
- 杨玉玲: [国际汉语教师语法教学手册](http://www.hep.com.cn/book/details?uuid=5274e5dc-1414-1000-8fa1-3fafc67de19c) (Handbook on Grammar Teaching for International Chinese Teachers). 高等教育出版社/Higher Education Press, 2012. ISBN 978-7-04-031682-7.
- Everson, Michael E.; Xiao, Yun： [*Teaching Chinese as a Foreign Language: Theories and Applications*](https://www.cheng-tsui.com/browse/professional-development-language-learning/teaching-chinese-as-a-foreign-language?id=20868). Cheng & Tsui, 2008.
- Waltz, Terry: [*TPRS  with Chinese Characteristics: Making Students Fluent and Literate Through Comprehensible Input*](https://squidforbrains.com/products/the-red-book). Squid for Brains, 2015. ISBN 978-0692442906. TPRS stands for [Teaching Proficiency through Reading and Storytelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TPR_Storytelling).
- 周健： [汉语课堂教学技巧与游戏](http://www.blcup.com/PInfo/index/2816) (Skills and Games for Chinese Classroom Instruction). Beijing Language and Culture University Press, 1998. ISBN 9787561926354.
- Yang, Wenhui: 劲松教汉语： 汉语课堂教学实用技巧72法. (Easy to Teach Chinese: 72 Practical Skills in Classroom Teaching of Chinese). World Publishing Company, 2009.
- Zhang Baolin: 汉语教学参考语法. Peking University Press, 2007.